# Image cannot be displayed in HTML

Tags: html, image, src

I got some encrypted url strings as the `src` attribute of `<img>` tags in my html page. For example:

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.111/business_id/ia8u7Eg8tTVungbUGxVGfh4GYf1tbnh3EyBBmsc1TapqV8/0" />
```

The link itself can be opened directly by the browser and can be displayed correctly. But this `<img>` tag in a html page is not displayed correctly with a bad image in the screen. And when I opened this link correctly in the browser, the image will be displayed in the page, apparently this is fetched from the cache.

[image]

I have been doing some research, with the developer tools, I track the request of the browser while opening this page. And here is the result:
[image]

Just find out may be it is the wrong format that cause this problem. When I opened in the browser, it is parsed correctly to jpeg:
[image]

Question is why is this happening? What can I do to fix this? I don't know the format, the server does. Suppose I want to specify the encoding of the `src` in `<img>` as jpeg programmatically , is this possible?

Comment: the problem is most definitely your URL `192.168.1.111` is a local address, are you trying to view the image on a server?

Comment: @slash197 No, this is an example, it's not the real ip, for some reason, I can't put it publicly. But that is a local address too, the server is a local server.

Comment: I only know to do something like this in PHP, but not javascript.

Comment: caching issue? does clearing the cache or opening the HTML in another browser hemake a difference?

Comment: Can you copy FULL http response or give me address? I might know what causes that problem

Comment: Also ypu can see that in first image, there's other initiator, and in second image is fetched from cache.

Comment: @kamil09875 This is in local server.  The second one has been cached, the first time I opened directly in browser( type the address hit enter ), the initiator is also `Other`

Comment: @kamil09875 problem is when opening directly I got the image, but when I put the address in a img tag things is not working.

Comment: Okay, but I need full http responses, from directly and img. Is it your server where image is stored?