# Change referer field in HTTP header

Tags: html, image, http-headers, src

After asking the question [Image cannot be displayed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769868/image-cannot-be-displayed-in-html) . I've been searching for a solution. I was lucky that I find the header of my request have a field named `referer`：

[image]

I think this is the cause of the problem. The local Server might have refused my request to avoid a Hotlinking. But the server is now online, I can't modify the white list. **Is there any way to fake a `referer` in HTML page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  This is something the browser controls, not your HTML.

The best you can do is proxy it server-side.  Then, you can do whatever you want with your request headers.

Comment: I want to use this link in my html `<img>` tag. How to proxy it server-side? If in PHP